# with openlayers , how do i make sure a list of points are all displayed?

Tags: javascript, mapping, openlayers

I have an OpenLayers map object, and I have added markers to a layer, and added it to the map.

But how do I make sure all the markers are in the display area?

Thanks,

Gil

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In order to display all markers on the map
Firstly,make sure you have all markers in one layer.
Secondly,you need to zoom to bound where all markers in marker layer are extended.
To do that,simply

```
   var bounds = markerLayer.getDataExtent();
   map.zoomToExtent(bounds);
   //has a second parameter that decides to find closest zoom level
   //default is false
```

Please check [OpenLayers Document for Marker Layer](http://dev.openlayers.org/docs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Markers-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Markers.getDataExtent)

Best Regards
Myra