# with openlayers , how do i make sure the markers in TWO layers are all dsiplayed

Tags: javascript, mapping, openlayers

I have markers in two marker layers,which i need to keep separate, so I can clear one or the other in the application.

What is the best way to make sure all markers are displayed.  Doing it for one layer is easy with [zoomToExtent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4084980/with-openlayers-how-do-i-make-sure-a-list-of-points-are-all-displayed). But how to do it for more then one layer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Get the bounds from layer 1, use .extend(layer 2's bounds), and then zoomToExtent on the extended bounds.

http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/BaseTypes/Bounds-js.html#OpenLayers.Bounds.extend

is the extend method on a bounds.

sketchy and quick, sorry....

Answer (score 0):

Use a new bounds object and use Bounds.extend.

```
var myNewBounds = Layer1.zoomToExtent.getExtent();
myNewBounds.extend(Layer2.zoomToExtent.getExtent());
```

Use that new bounds variable to set the bounds on your map.  The syntax is wrong, but that's the direction you want to go.

Comment: getExtent on a layer is "A Bounds object which represents the lon/lat bounds of the current viewPort." You don't want the viewPort, and zoomToExtent is a method of maps, not layers. Do "Layer1.maxExtent" (without parens, its a property not a method).